# If I linebreak 2x in source, does latex assume a new paragraph?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

If I linebreak 2x in source, does latex automatically assume a new paragraph?

Since I am noticing that when I do, whatever I write next comes with extra indentation.

```
something_1 something_1 something_1 something_1
something_2 something_2 something_2 something_2
```

will produce

> something_1 something_1 something_1 something_1 something_2 something_2 something_2 something_2

but

```
something_1 something_1 something_1 something_1

something_2 something_2 something_2 something_2
```

will produce

> something_1 something_1 something_1 something_1
>
> (some space here) something_2 something_2 something_2 something_2

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, that's normal behavior.

Comment: @egreg Hey thanks for the response. Sorry for the potentially trivial question. Im still learning!

Comment: @egreg How would I disable this feature then, say for readability reasons? (extra vertical whitespace helps in sectioning) Is there anything I can do besides `\noindent`?

Comment: The normal usage is to place a `%` sign at the beginning of the empty line.  The `%` character starts a comment, so you can have an (almost) empty line in the source, if you need it for readability, without TeX “seeing” that line (because it is commented out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a built-in feature: an empty line (precisely, a line containing nothing else than blank spaces) is converted into `\par`. So, typing

```
abc def

ghi lmn
```

is equivalent to typing

```
abc def \par ghi lmn
```

(the space after `f` is generated by the end-of-line and then removed by `\par` during the line breaking process).

Note that a line containing `%` is not an empty line in the sense above, so typing

```
abc def
%
ghi lmn
```

is equivalent to typing the single line

```
abc def ghi lmn
```

---

You could disable the feature by declaring

```
\endlinechar=32
```

in your document preamble. But then you'd have to explicitly mark up your end of paragraphs by an explicit `\par` command.

---

If you want instead to remove the indentation, declare

```
\parindent=0pt
```

(in plain TeX) or

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

(in LaTeX). Don't do it: indentation at the start of paragraphs has been in use for centuries and nobody has found a better method, yet.